# Secure Instagram request with php using cURL

Tags: php, api, http, curl, instagram

I've been struggling with this for a while now and still could not find a clear guide to do this.

If I want to make requests to Instagram API using cURL, I do it like this:

```
<?php

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=MY_TOKEN";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

It works fine, but it's a bit insecure and thats why I'd like to do it with **signed request**, which uses this **sig**-parameter.

Now, I can easily create that **sig**-parameter(signature key) using the code found from [here](https://instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/), but how to use that signature with PHP?

I'm totally confused.

Comment: If you scroll down on that page you linked to you will see an example in PHP!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that only creates the signature key/value. I need to use it but don't know how.

Comment: I believe you pass it into the URL as `sig` query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is hinted at Instagram's documentation page. Still this is how I did:

- Use the generate signature php function mentioned there to generate `$sig`.
- Attach it to your endpoint using http_build_query() like this:

  ```
  $endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/";

  $secured_get_fields = array(
      "access_token" => $access_token,
      //other get fields as required
      "sig" => $sig
  );

  $api_url = $endpoint . "?" . http_build_query($secured_get_fields);
  ```
- Call with this `$api_url`

Hope it helps!